# How to get word2index from gensim

Tags: gensim

By doc we can use this to read a word2vec model with genism

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('word2vec.50d.txt', binary=False)
```

This is an index-to-word mapping, that is, e.g., `model.index2word[2]`, how to derive an inverted mapping (word-to-index) based on this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The mappings from word-to-index are in the `KeyedVectors` `vocab` property, a dictionary with objects that include an `index` property.

For example:

```
word = "whatever"  # for any word in model
i = model.vocab[word].index
model.index2word[i] == word  # will be true
```

Comment: API changed now, use `model.wv.vocab.get(word).index`

Comment: 4.0 update, use `model.wv.key_to_index.get(word)` and `w2v_model.wv.index_to_key[idx]`

Comment: Keep changing the API every few years, watch your user levels decline.

the curse of free software

Comment: In Gensim, there've been pretty small changes, pretty rarely, with long periods of backward-compatibility, and with clear documentation of how to adapt. The last notable breaking changes, for Gensim-4.0.0, were in March 2021. And, not fixing problems in older APIs leaes known problems & area prone-to-misunderstanding to fester indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler solution would be to enumerate `index2word`

```
word2index = {token: token_index for token_index, token in enumerate(w2v.index2word)} 
word2index['hi'] == 30308  # True
```